# how to parse NSString by removing 2 folders in path in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsstring

I need to parse NSString in Objective-C.. i.e if input path string is /a/b/c/d , i need to parse the path string to get the outout like /a/b/
How do i achieve it? 
input path string:/a/b/c/d
expected output path string:/a/b/
Please help me out.

Thank You.
Suse.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use `stringByDeletingLastPathComponent` twice:

```
NSString *pathStr = @"/a/b/c/d";
NSString *path = [[pathStr stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
NSLog(@"%@", path);
```

Returns `/a/b`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
NSString *path = @"/a/b/c/d";
NSArray *components = [path pathComponents]

NSLog(@"%@", [components objectAtIndex: 1]); // <- output a
NSLog(@"%@", [components objectAtIndex: 2]); // <- output b
NSLog(@"%@", [components lastObject]); // <- output d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *path = @"/a/b/c/d";


int howManyFoldersNeedsToBeDeleded = 2;

for (int i = 1; i <= howManyFoldersNeedsToBeDeleded; i++) {


     path = [path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];




}



NSLog(@"output : %@ \n\n",path);
```